# How do I enable CustomRetryHandler on camunda

Tags: camunda

When starting camunda version 7.7 on tomcat we use a file like this one
https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-platform/blob/master/distro/tomcat/assembly/src/conf/bpm-platform.xml

How can we enable a CustomRetryHandler ?

Ive found out that if we use version 7.8 its enabled by default. But we are on 7.7 and have no plan on moving up right now.

Ive found this page.
https://forum.camunda.org/t/custom-retry-configuration-in-camunda-wildlfy-subsystem/5345

But if I try to add

```
<property name="customPostBPMNParseListeners">
                          org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.bpmn.parser.FoxFailedJobParseListener
                    </property>
                    <property name="failedJobCommandFactory">
                          org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.jobexecutor.FoxFailedJobCommandFactory
                    </property>
```

I get this error

```
Caused by: org.camunda.bpm.engine.ProcessEngineException: ENGINE-08039 Cannot set property 'customPostBPMNParseListeners' on instance of class 'org.camun
da.bpm.engine.impl.cfg.StandaloneProcessEngineConfiguration'
        at org.camunda.bpm.container.impl.ContainerIntegrationLogger.cannotSetValueForProperty(ContainerIntegrationLogger.java:281)
        at org.camunda.bpm.container.impl.metadata.PropertyHelper.applyProperty(PropertyHelper.java:87)
        at org.camunda.bpm.container.impl.metadata.PropertyHelper.applyProperties(PropertyHelper.java:106)
        at org.camunda.bpm.container.impl.deployment.StartProcessEngineStep.performOperationStep(StartProcessEngineStep.java:104)
        at org.camunda.bpm.container.impl.spi.DeploymentOperation.execute(DeploymentOperation.java:116)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.camunda.bpm.container.impl.metadata.PropertyHelper.applyProperty(PropertyHelper.java:84)
        ... 20 more
```

Hope someone can post me in the right direction =)

Answer (score 1):

It is enabled by default. So no changes are needed.

I guess its different when you use a deployment descriptor.